# How would a PHP Dependency Injection Container look like in code when defining a class?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to learn more about DiC/IoC with PHP and I want to understand the full process.

Am I correct in saying that a PHP DI Container could define a class like:

```
$container->addClass("Mailer", function()
{
   $mailConfig = env("..."); // Example setup for the Mailer class...
   return new Mailer($mailConfig);

});
```

Is this something that could work and is best practice? I could then have a file which defines all classes like the example above?